# Rendering camera output to a Render Texture and displaying with a clear background

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I have a hololens app made in unity using the URP. I added a second camera of render type base and set the output texture to a custom render texture. I set the camera background type as uninitialized. I created a material and set the render texture as the surface input base map. I then created a plane, dragged the material onto it, and positioned it in the field of view of the main camera. I added a cube in the field of view of the second camera. I followed this link to do this... [Rendering to a Render Texture](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@7.2/manual/rendering-to-a-render-texture.html)

The result is I see the plane and the output of the second camera (cube) in the main camera, which is what I want. But I see the entire plane as well as a black background. Is there a way that I can make the plane appear transparent so only the cube is displayed?

[Camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWPeE.png)

[Render Texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9ndb.png)

[Material](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvz1j.png)

[Plane with render texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7CKf.png)

[Main camera with cube and black background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmUgA.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plane's material is set to `Surface Type` -> `Opaque`.

Changing that to

- `Surface Type` -> `Transparent`
- `Blending Mode` -> `Alpha`

should solve your issue.

[image]

Comment: Thanks derHugo. I tried that. But it makes by cube transparent too. I don't understand why it works for your model. Not fully transparent. But as it it had an alpha of 0.3.

Comment: I made another sample project and it worked just like you said. But I still don't know why my main project doesn't work that way. One thing I noticed is that the camera renderer is "Forward Renderer" for the project that doesn't work and "UniversalRenderPipelineAsset_Renderer" for the project that does work. but in each case there is only one choice. Any chance that is the problem?

Comment: @LeoReubelt in your camera instead of `Background Type` -> `Uninitialized` rather try to use `Solid Color` and make sure its alpha is set to `0`

Comment: no difference. also, changing surface type back to opaque with a background alpha of 0 makes the background fully opaque again.

Comment: It was something to do with the material associated with my cube. I made a new cube and it works. Thanks for the help.